# Как имитировать вращение колеса, отправляя запрос?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Вот есть мини-игра: https://games.api.barcodes.no/play/81363b0f-6d33-4e0f-98c3-07d4820e7918
[image: 1]
В которой нужно крутить колесо, при прокрутке вызываются 2 запроса:

> https://games.api.barcodes.no/spin/XXX?Language=default

> https://games.api.barcodes.no/play/XXX?View=Reward&Template=_PartialLayout&Language=default

Где XXX - код игры
Вызывая эти 2 запроса, сервер возвращает ответ, подобный этому:

> [
> 0.000322767208032586,
> 6.28318530717959,
> 0.000322767208032586,
> 0.0635923552142909,
> 12.5477430767723,
> 4647.3122506564
> ]

Но ничего не происходит, приз остается не полученным.

```
await axios({
        url: `https://games.api.barcodes.no/spin/${link}?Language=default`,
        method: "POST",
        data: 'SpinForce=0.09',
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" }
    })
    await axios({ url: `https://games.api.barcodes.no/play/${link}?View=Reward&Template=_PartialLayout&Language=default`, 
                 method: "POST" 
    })
```

Comment: уверены, что во втором вызове метод должен быть ПОСТ, а не ГЕТ? что возвращает этот запрос?

Comment: смотря в network, возвращаются 2 POST запроса

Comment: как могут вернуться два пост запроса, если по коду вы отправляете два этих пост запроса? возвращаются вам ответы на ваши запросы

Comment: исходя из очень малого кол-ва информации, я бы посоветовал попробовать для начала заменить второй запрос на: await axios({ url: `https://games.api.barcodes.no/play/${link}?View=Reward&Template=_PartialLayout&Language=default`, 
                 method: "GET" 
    })

Comment: если это не поможет, то выводите результат запроса в консоль - const res = await axios({ url: `https://games.api.barcodes.no/play/${link}?View=Reward&Template=_PartialLayout&Language=default`, 
                 method: "POST" 
    }); console.log(res);

Comment: и напишите сюда, что за объект вернется. по общим правилам ПОСТ - редактирует данные на сервере и может возвращать не данные, а результат редактирования - 1 или 0

Comment: Действительно работает, сначала вызываем POST, потом GET. Спасибо за помощь!